# Recognize eye borders

Tags: c#, computer-vision, emgucv

My task is to recognize eye borders (not pupil but whole eye).

I can't take the white part of image even using HSV filtering.

I use filtering by hue and saturation and get no result:

```
Image<Gray, byte> huefilter = imghue.InRange(new Gray(Color.White.GetHue()-10), new Gray(Color.White.GetHue() + 10));
Image<Gray, byte> saturationfilter = imgsaturation.InRange(new Gray(Color.White.GetSaturation() - 10), new Gray(Color.White.GetSaturation() + 10));
Image<Gray, byte> resultImg = huefilter.And(saturationfilter);
```

Sample images:[One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1RXI.jpg) [Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3Vjn.jpg) [Three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cITAU.jpg)

Please give an advise how to get the light zone around pupil with help of c# EmguCV.

Comment: Have you consider using a cascade?
I used a pre-trained model for eye detection.

Comment: @AkshayBahadur eye is already detected. The problem is to recognize the shape of the eye.

Comment: See the gif here https://github.com/akshaybahadur21/Drowsiness_Detection

Comment: Great.... Happy coding..!!